# How to launch dataflow template job with idempotence?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a system that will launch a dataflow template job, then hours later, might attempt to launch the same job using the same request. For all launch template requests after the first, I do not want to start another dataflow job or replace the existing one. I want to receive the first dataflow job or fail.

At first I thought the job `name` would provide the idempotence, but if the first job finishes before the request is resent, then the second job with the same `name` will start and duplicate the work of the first job.

I also noticed Jobs have a `clientRequestId` specifically for idempotent job creation. However, I don't see how I can specify the `clientRequestId` when using the [launch template API](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.templates/launch).

Is there a way to launch a dataflow template job with idempotence?

---

For example, I would need `LaunchTemplateParams` like:

```
{
  jobName: "my-job",
  clientRequestId: "unique-id"
}
```

Such that if I call LaunchTemplate with `clientRequestId="unique-id"` multiple times, dataflow will not create a second job if a previous job had the same id, regardless of whether the previous job is running or is finished.

Comment: can you add a code snippet of what you imagine the call does? You can check the existence of a job via its job name with the gcloud utility or the Dataflow API. Does that fit your use case?

Comment: Hmm, maybe. Is there a way to look up by jobName instead of jobId?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sort of script of some kind that you can modify to query the job name first, before trying to create the job, you could query it like this:

```
gcloud dataflow jobs list --filter="name=your-job-name" --format=json
```

This will return something like this:

```
[
  {
    "creationTime": "2021-03-30 00:05:10",
    "id": "2021-03-29_18_05_12-8681413788758",
    "location": "us-central1",
    "name": "your-job-name",
    "state": "Running",
    "stateTime": "2021-03-30 00:05:20",
    "type": "Batch"
  }
]
```

Which you can then parse to figure out the state of the job and choose whether to launch your template. Is that useful?